# laravel 5.6 add array to json column

Tags: json, laravel

i have a json column in my table. I want to be one of properties (passengers_id) array.

How i can add new (id) to the (passengers_id) and remains the old.

[image]

Comment: you need to add array in passengers_id right?

Comment: yes, i want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$existing_json='{"flight_id":181,"adults":"2","children":0,
"infants":0,"total":240,"departure":"16:5","passangers_number":0,
"passengers_id":178}';
$add_array=["id"=>178];

$arr=json_decode($existing_json);
$arr->passengers_id=$add_array;
$new_json=json_encode($arr);
```

Expected Output

```
{"flight_id":181,"adults":"2","children":0,"infants":0,"total":240,"departure":"16:5","passangers_number":0,"passengers_id":{"id":178}}
```

Comment: please i want dot it by Laravel not Json.

Comment: @Swaramuhemed i think now it will helps you

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not a solution.